# Rebranding Centos Linux 7 with changing branding of centos name from /etc/os-release, grub boot loader

Tags: linux, operating-system, centos7, rhel7

For rebranding Centos 7 recently started changing required OS components, except few things everything works as expected. At the first stage of the installation process shows like so,

```
             **CustomOS**
Install CustomOS 7
Test this media & install CustomOS7
```

But after select **Install CustomOS 7** OS boots up with pre checking all configuration and shows welcome to **Centos Linux 7**,

```
Welcome to Centos Linux 7(Core)
```

Which is required to change **Centos Linux 7** to **Custom Linux 7**. To achieve goal already done few things successfully by following [RedHat document](http://ANACONDA%20CUSTOMIZATION%20GUIDE), [Talk:Build an Official ISO](https://wiki.contribs.org/Talk:Build_an_Official_ISO) and few other blogs but mentioned required changes doesn't work as requiremnt. Also following requirements need to do,

- after completion of OS installation Gurb boot loader will show Custom OS instead of Centos
- `cat /etc/os-release` will show **Custom OS** instead of **Centos**

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify `centos-release.spec` file for your required changes. Follow the below instructions.

**Prepare Environment:**

```
# yum install rpm-build gcc make
# mkdir -p ~/rpmbuild/{BUILD,BUILDROOT,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS}
# echo '%_topdir %(echo $HOME)/rpmbuild' > ~/.rpmmacros
```

**Extract Source RPM:**

```
# rpmbuild --rebuild centos-release-7-9.2009.0.el7.centos.src.rpm
```

**Install Source RPM:**

```
# rpm -ivh centos-release-7-9.2009.0.el7.centos.src.rpm
```

**Modify centos-release.spec file:**

```
# cd ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/

# vim centos-release.spec

%define product_family CustomOS Linux
```

**Build RPM:**

```
# cd ~/rpmbuild
# rpmbuild -ba SPECS/centos-release.spec
# cd ~/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64
```

Copy centos-release-7-9.2009.0.el7.centos.rpm and replace this with existing one. Then build your OS.

Comment: Thanks its working partially but how can i change when OS boots up with pre checking all configuration and shows Welcome to Centos Linux 7(Core)?